# OCR, tesseract.js: How do I match values to labels?

Tags: javascript, ocr, tesseract, text-recognition, tesseract.js

I'm using tesseract.js to get text from a W2 form.  I'm having trouble trying to figure out how I could get match up the values of the form to the labels. Like How can I match up the label 'employee social security number' with the value social security number?

Comment: If you know the W2 image will always have the same layout, you can split the image up and run tesseract on each piece. That's what I did in one of my side-projects: https://github.com/SidneyNemzer/siege-stats/blob/master/src/components/App.js#L82-L151. You'll have to manually determine the coordinates of each field, of course. I just did that by trial-and-error.

Comment: @Sidney Thanks for the response.  Can you explain to me what the subcanvas and subContext is for ?

Comment: Are you familiar with [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)? In my app, canvas is used to grab pieces of an image, then pass them to Tesseract. There's a large canvas (`scoreboardCanvas`) that holds the main image. The `subCanvas` is used to hold the sub-section of the image that's being worked on. It's reused for every piece (there's 10 'subsections' in my app). A `context`, in regards to canvas, is the object that can manipulate the pixels of the canvas.

Comment: @Sidney Thanks! i took your advice and cut up the image with canvas. Then I scanned them all individually.